# Time range query algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have a table with ID, and start & end time in milliseconds

```
ID Start End
1..0.....15
2..17....23
3..23....30
4..35....45
```

and so on.

I have a query `find records with range of 18 and 28`. The query will select rows which time range covers the range from query time. For above query, `record 2 and 3` are valid.

My approach would be

```
select * from table where
start between 18 and 28 or    // record 3 is selected
end between 18 and 28;        // record 2 is selected
```

That's good enough.

Then I have another case where `find records with range of 5 to 10`.

The above query won't return anything. So, I add an extra statement.

```
select * from table where
start between 5 and 10 or    
end between 5 and 10 or
(start < 5 and end > 10);    // record 1 is selected.
```

My question is to verify if my approach is correct or is there any well-known algorithm that takes care of this problem?

I am pretty sure there are other questions of similar nature. I couldn't think of the correct keyword to find them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if one range intersects another range you might use the following predicate:

```
start < 10 AND end > 5
```

Comment: damn.. so simple. I forgot the work `range`. thanks so much.